# How to render HTML form from schema using formencode?

Tags: python, html, forms, pylons, formencode

I'm using [formencode](http://formencode.org/) for validating and submitting forms in my Pylons application. The documentation says that it can be used also for generating forms, but there is no any example. I even found the old topic which says it can be done with

```
form = HTMLForm(form_template, FormSchema)
form.render()
```

but for the latest version of formencode it doesn't work.

So, someone please help, how can I generate a HTML using the simplest form Schema?

```
class LoginForm(formencode.Schema):
    allow_extra_fields = True
    filter_extra_fields = True
    email = formencode.validators.String(not_empty=True)
    password = formencode.validators.String(not_empty=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Formencode library doesn't generate html for forms.**

The code you are referring to uses formencode.htmlform module which no longer exists as it was [removed in 1.1 release](http://formencode.org/news.html#id4) because, as author said, [it was dumb](http://formencode.org/news.html#id13). :)

I think you may have mistaken that kind of functionality with different feature of this lib, namely filling form values after unsuccessful submission which is realised by [formencode.htmlfill module](http://formencode.org/htmlfill.html).

Comment: Thanks for answer, I'm trying to use Pylons after Django, so all the time I think it should be simple :)

Answer (score 0):

What zifot said about formencode was spot on.  I would only add that you should look at FormAlchemy and Sprox, two libraries built to generate forms from database schemas.

Comment: I'm using MongoKit, so almost all form generation engines won't help because of different model description.